# Looping over rows of a CSV imported dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, rows

I am trying to print rows of a dataframe one by one.
I only manage to loop over the columns instead of the rows:

first I am importing from a csv:

```
table_csv = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\table.csv',sep=';', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Next, I convert into a datframe using pandas:

```
table_dataframe = DataFrame(table_csv)
```

I then start the for loop as follows:

```
for row in table_dataframe:
print(row)
```

It however loops over the columns instead of the instead over the row. However i need to perform alterations on rows. Does anybody know where this goes wrong or has an alternative solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

[Check out answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

In short this is how you'd do it:

```
for index, row in table_dataframe.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

Comment: that prints out the rows separated per column, so it starts with first column and then just prints all the rows contained and then moves to the second column etc..I need it to print out the rows one by one without this column separation

Answer (score 0):

When you import a csv using `pd.read_csv`, the resultant object is a pandas dataframe anyway, no need to perform `table_dataframe = DataFrame(table_csv)` again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).